# Texstudio quick start wizard options managing

Tags: packages, texstudio, automation, options

My aim was to add some language packages to the quick start wizard.
Thus I cliqued the plus symbol of the 'other options' option. Then I was asked to type in this new option:

[image: New: ...]

Thinking that it was the name of the new option that was asked, I wrote (for the first one) "french". But that gave me that: (a 'french' option in \documentclass)

[image: 'french' becomes an option]

The Question:

How can I:

- delete these pointless options?
- add some optionally packages like 'babel' as an other checkable package? (like the 'graphicx' package)

thanks! :·)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with the Quick Start Wizard. It's really only intended to create a basic document. Given that user requirements can be quite different, trying to add additional stuff would be quite a lot of work and make the dialog really complex.

If you need more freedom, you should use [a template](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION12a) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know if it is possible to delete 'french' and 'german' (per GUI or per file modification)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (at least TeXstudio >= 3.1.2) the babel is part of the wizard.

But let me answer your still open second question about how to delete "these pointless options"

In short: It's in your `texstudio.ini`

In more detail:

0. Close TeXstudio
1. Open your config file. The location depends on your operating system:

   - Linux: In your home directory (in the hidden `.config` folder): `$HOME/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini`
   - Windows: I read that it's in your appdata folder. I don't have Windows so I cannot comment on that. Probably it's a hidden folder. (Feel free to add this information)
2. Search for the `Tools/User` lines. There you can replace your added values to `@Invalid()`